# SQLite problem with getting the higher value of a specific column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating a Flight Planning Application where users can create multiple flights with each flight having its own expenses report. For each flight that the user has created, they will each have a button that can be pressed to open another activity called `AddExpenses.class` and from that class user will be able to add multiple expenses to that particular trip.

Since this explanation is long and will be a little confusing the "()" I use is referring to the table. For example, (flights) will be referring to the flight table.

I have two tables, one is (flights) and the other is (transactions). Each flight can have many transactions records (transactions) but I can't show the primary key when the user views all from (transactions) because for the (transactions) table, the primary key is named transactions_id and it autoincrements.

This is a problem because if the FIRST flight has 3 transactions records that have been added, the will be 3 rows added in the (transactions) table with transaction_id of 1,2,3. 
And when the user add transactions from a SECOND flight, the transaction_id which is the primary key, will not start from 1 but continue from 4... and so on.

So I'm trying to add 2 additional columns in my (transactions) table which is id_shown and flightposition_id.
The "id_shown" column will loop and start from 1 again if the user adds transaction records from a different flight. And the "flightposition_id" just shows which rows of transaction records in (transactions) are under that particular "flight_id" in (flights) so that I can show the right transaction records in (transactions) when they are viewing the records from a particular flight.

This is the onCreate method in my DatabaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper for my (transactions) table :-

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TRANSACTION_TABLE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, AMOUNT DOUBLE NOT NULL, CATEGORY TEXT NOT NULL, NOTE TEXT, TRANSACTION_ID TEXT NOT NULL, FLIGHT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (FLIGHT_ID) REFERENCES FLIGHT_TABLE(id) )");
```

This is the add button in my "AddExpenses" class to add more transactions :-

```
public void AddTransactions (final String flightposition_id) {
        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myDb.getTransactionData()

                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertTransactionData(amount.getText().toString(), category, note.getText().toString(), transaction_id, flightposition_id);

                if (isInserted = true) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "Transaction Inserted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clearText();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddExpenses.this, "Transaction not Inserted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                textView_id.setText(transaction_id);

            }
        });
    }
```

For now I get the flightposition_id by passing it from my MainActivity that extends RecyclerView.Adapter to "AddExpenses" class :-

```
button_addexpenses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddExpenses.class);
                intent.putExtra("Position", getAdapterPosition());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Everything is working pretty okay I just have one problem now, if I'm trying to add transaction records from the SECOND flight, I want my app to check through all rows in (transactions) that have columns "flightposition_id" with a value that is the same as the position I'm in (SECOND flight means a position of "1").

And with all (transactions) rows with the flight_position of "1", I want the app to add my next transaction one integer higher than the highest or latest "id_shown" value. If the highest is 4, then a counter will +1 making it 5 and so on.

Can you guide me and give me a brief code on what i should add to my add "button" in AddExpenses.class? I know its a long explanation and may be confusing, thanks a million for taking the time to read !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to execute a query like this:

```
"SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM transactions WHERE flight_id=" + position
```

if I understood correctly,  
and get the max number that is already stored in the db, then increment it by 1 and save the new row.  
Edit:

```
Cursor transactionlatestid = myDb.getLatestTransactionID(temp_position); 
if (transactionlatestid.getCount() == 0) { 
    temp_id = 1; 
} else {
    transactionlatestid.moveToFirst();
    temp_id = transactionlatestid.getInt(0); 
    temp += 1; 
} 
String transaction_id = String.valueOf(temp_id);
```

Is it `temp` or `temp_id` you want to increase?

Comment: so I need to execute that query from my DatabaseHelper class as something like this? Cursor transactionresult = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TRANSACTION_TABLE,null); but with a sql query that you said? After that how would I +1 to the MAX(transaction_id) from the AddExpenses class in my add "button"?

Comment: @shz1998 if you execute this query like a regular rawQuery, you will get one single value that you will store in a variable and increment this variable +1 and by using an `INSERT` statement or `insert()` method of the `DatabaseHelper` class you will add the new row having the value of this variable.

Comment: Understood sir ! The only problem now is that the part of flightposition_id = ? how do I pass "position" from my AddExpenses class to my DatabaseHelper class cuz I cant do it the way I normally do using intent

Comment: @shz1998 you pass it as a parameter of a method, just like you pass parameters here `myDb.insertTransactionData(amount.getText().toString(), category, note.getText().toString(), transaction_id, flightposition_id);`

Comment: I've managed to put pass "position" into DatabaseHelper and into the query successfully but I was using a Cursor method to run the rawQuery, and in my AddExpenses class I can't get the single value as you said as "int flightid_position = myDb.getLatestTransactionID(position);" it says Cursor cannot be converted to int

Comment: It seems to me that the `getLatestTransactionID()` method returns a cursor. If this is the case then you will get the value you want with: `Cursor c = myDb.getLatestTransactionID(position); int flightid_position = c.getInt(0);`

Comment: Omg so much problems keep coming :( this is the SQL query i wrote -> SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM transactions WHERE (flight_id= position) in my rawQuery and my Cursor method name-> public Cursor getLatestTransactionID(int position) and my calling for the getLatestTransactionID method in AddExpenses ->Cursor transactionlatestid = myDb.getLatestTransactionID(temp_position); but when I run my app, it crashes and the logcat says android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: position (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT MAX(transaction_id) FROM transactions WHERE (flight_id= position)

Comment: I'm glad I saved your life!

Comment: If you dont mind be asking another question sorry I'm a newbie programmer :p I added this code to intialise it to 1 if there is no record found using getLatestTransaction ID but I'm getting a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException. the code -> Cursor transactionlatestid = myDb.getLatestTransactionID(temp_position); if (transactionlatestid.getCount() == 0) { temp_id = 1; } else if { temp_id = transactionlatestid.getInt(0); temp += 1; } String transaction_id = String.valueOf(temp_id);